# Dynamicly edit the DOM using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I've this code written 4 + and - buttons for cart. But I have to change the quantity by manually entering the number in the input field

```
<div class="quantity-stepper hidden-xs">
    <button class="less js-less" onclick="changeQty('${commerceItemId}','-', ${status.index});">-</button>
    <input type="text" id="quantityToChange${status.index}" class="product-value" value="${currentItem.quantity}" />
    <button class="more js-more" onclick="changeQty('${commerceItemId}','+', ${status.index});">+</button>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        var quantityProdAry = $( "input[id*='quantityToChange']" );
        $.each(quantityProdAry, function(key, value) {
            if(parseInt(value.value) > 0 ) {
                $('.js-less').prop('disabled', false);
            }
            else {
                $('.js-less').prop('disabled', true);
            }
        });
    });

    function changeQty(commerceItem,operation, index){
        var quantity;
        var prevQuantity = parseInt($('#quantityToChange'+index).val());
        var index = parseInt(index);
        if(operation == '+') {
            quantity = (prevQuantity*1) + 1;
            if(parseInt(quantity) > 0 ) {
                $('.js-less').prop('disabled', false);
            }
            else {
                $('.js-less').prop('disabled', true);
            }
        }
        else {
            if(parseInt(prevQuantity) > 0 ) {
                $('.js-less').prop('disabled', false);
                quantity = (prevQuantity*1) - 1;
            }
            else {
                $('.js-less').prop('disabled', true);
            }
        }
        $('#value'+commerceItem+'index'+index).val(quantity);     

        //$('#quantityToChange'+index).val(quantity) 
        $('#changeQty').click();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Please, at the very least, unminify this code.

Comment: Please make your code readable first. its so messy

Comment: plz refer to this fiddle.. facing issue with code format.. https://jsfiddle.net/qa0y62hf/2/
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: @Priyankarathi can you please explain what you want ?